# Google App Engine Flexible Environment crashes

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Currently, I'm developing a web application using Scala and Play Framework and I run it on Google App Engine Flexible Environment. In general, everything works well, but sometimes application instance crashes for some reason. There is no any errors like OutOfMemory or something else. It just crashes and tries to restart JVM. Also, application works when I run it on my own laptop. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Kv8afLkpSfRk00XzBoTTJlV0k/view?usp=sharing) where you can download sample of logs.

May be someone has faced to similar problem and knows how to solve it?

UPD Updated the link.

Comment: Can you please add the most relevant snippet of your log in your question? The link doesn't seem to work. You can also look at the vm.shutdown logs to see if there's anything useful https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs#shutdown_logs

Comment: @KaranGoel I've updated the link, now it works.